# If $5 \times 12 = 104$, how much is $10 \times 11$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

Question is in the title, this is for my analysis course. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Hint: think of the numbers as being expressed in base $b$ instead of base $10$. You are being told that $5(b+2) = b^2+4$. So $b$ is ....

Comment: @CameronWilliams He needs to find the right base

Comment: Titles are for titles; question bodies are for question bodies. When you read an article in the paper, do the first sentence say "The news is in the title", or is the body of the article self-contained?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since 5 and 2 appear in the 'ones place' of the first equation, we know that the base is higher than both these numbers. Then:

$$10\cdot11=110$$

...just like in our usual number system.

Let $b$ denote the number base. Now in base b, the number $10$ represents $b$, the number $100$ represents $b^2$, and so on.

Now in base 10, we can re-write our equation as: $$5\times 12 = 104 \Rightarrow 5\cdot(b+2)=b^2+4$$

$$5b+10=b^2+4$$
$$b^2-5b-6=0$$
This polynomial's only positive root is at $b=6$, so that must be the base we are working in.

Now we can rewrite $10\times11$ in base-10:

$$10\times 11 =b\times(b+1)\Rightarrow6\cdot(6+1)=6\cdot7=42$$

---

Now to make sure, we can can convert that back to base 6 and make sure it looks like $110$:

$$42=36+6+0=b^2+b\Rightarrow110$$

Great, it works out!

Answer (score 3):

Provided the base is 2 or larger, you have $10\times 11 = 110$.

Comment: It also works if the base is equal to 2.

Comment: Yerright, Dan.  What's interesting is that the hypothesis is entirely superfluous.

Comment: Well, it's really just $b(b+1)=b^2+b$...

Comment: Multiply by 2 in binary (10) is just left shift or appending zero at the end, in the same way here also it is 10 x 11 = 110, we don't need to calculate the base in the given problem

Answer (score 2):

$ 5\times 12\  =\, 104\ $ in base $\,b\,$ means
$5(b\!+\!2) = b^2\!+4\, \Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{b^2 = 5b+6}$
$ 10(11) = \color{#c00}b(b\!+\!1)\, =\, \color{#0a0}{b^2}\!+b = \color{#c00}6(b\!+\!1)\,\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{b = 6} $